# Select specific items within yaml sequence in haml

Tags: ruby, yaml, haml, middleman

I'm building a website with Middleman and trying to access data from specific key-value pairs within a yaml sequence via a partial in haml, as follows:

**yaml**

```
# people.yml

- jack:
  fruit: Apples
  veg: Cabbage
- jill:
  fruit: Oranges
  veg: Spinach
```

**haml**

```
-# index.html.haml

= partial "some_partial",
   locals => { :fruit => data.people.jack.fruit }
```

For some reason `- jack` is returning an 'undefined method' error. If I remove the dash, and therefore sequence, I can obviously access `fruit` fine. I presume the sequence means `- jack` is nested deeper than just `jack`. If so, nested within what?

The reason I have this setup is because I'm calling the whole sequence within a loop on other pages. But in certain places I just want snippets from select items.

The short question: how should you access specific key-value pairs within a yaml sequence in haml?

Comment: It's not that `jack` is nested deeper, it's just that it's accessed by sequence, e.g. `people[0]`.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I see, thank you. I'll test when I can, but does this mean each item can only be accessed according to where it is indexed, ie. 0, 1, 2 ...?

Answer (score 3):

You may want to structure your YAML as follows...

```
# people.yml

- jack:
    fruit: Apples
    veg: Cabbage
- jill:
    fruit: Oranges
    veg: Spinach
```

Nesting the fruit and veg gives you the relation of people.jack.fruit

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'd presumed this was already the case as the loop was matching the correct data

Comment: The original structure was equvalent to `[{'jack' => nil, 'fruit' => 'Apples', 'veg' => 'Cabbage'}, {'jill' => nil, 'fruit' => 'Oranges', 'veg' => 'Spinach'}]` which is to say an array of two hashes.  Looping through the array would let you access all `fruit` data and all `veg` data but doesn't explicity nest both under a person name.

Comment: `data.people.jack.fruit`, with `fruit` correctly nested within `- jack:`, as above, still returns 'undefined method'. `data.people[0].jack.fruit`, however, works fine. I presumed `- jack:`, with the dash, acted as the key for its nested items and so thought I could just select `jack`. However, it appears the `- ` simply denotes the sequence item containing `jack:` within the array `people`, and so is separate from `jack`. It seems you therefore have to select the array item, eg. `[0]`, and then, if there are items nested within `[0]`, select the appropriate key, eg. `jack`. Is this the answer?

Comment: Yes all sequence items are selected by offset.